# SQLITE3 query doesn't return what I want it to within PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I open my sq3d fine, but when I try to do a SELECT on one of my tables it seems to not return the results I excpect. Here is the php code:

```
$buildingArray = array();

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->open('Database.s3db');
}
}


$db = new MyDB();

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploadData";
$result1 = $db->query($query1);
$u = $result1->fetchArray();
echo "<br/>Size of u: ".sizeOf($u)."<br/>";

for($i=0; $i<sizeOf($u); $i++){
echo "<br/>Items: ".$u[$i]."<br/>";
}
```

This is what is in my Database:

tbl_uploadData : b_id - 1,2,3,4 : where 1,2,3,4 are the items within the fields, b_id the field name and tbl_uploadData the table.

I expect to get 1, 2, 3 and 4 to return in the fetchArray()

All i get in return is:

```
Size of u: 2
Items: 1
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPexcel\Tests\StrategicExcel.php on line 72
Items:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, as spaced monkey mentioned, fetchArray() only returns one result at a time. So by adding a while loop and a couple of references to my b_id, it should work. I've modified my code to:

```
$databaseName = "Database.s3db";

$db2 = new SQLite3($databaseName); 
    $sql = "SELECT b_id FROM tbl_uploadData"; 
    $result = $db2->query($sql);//->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); 
    $row = array(); 

    $i = 0; 
     while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 
         if(!isset($res['b_id'])) continue; 
            $row[$i]['b_id'] = $res['b_id']; 
            $i++; 
      } 
      print_r($row);
```

Hope this helps if anyone comes across this problem in the future, TY

Answer (score 0):

fetchArray() only gets 1 row at a time, you need to call it for every row. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-array.php

You should be able to:

```
while ( $u = $result1->fetchArray() ) {
    echo "<br/>Items: ".$u['b_id']."<br/>";
}
```

I don't know why sizeof($u) is returning 2 though.

Comment: I've found out another way to do it, thanks anyway, I didn't know that fetchArray() only returns one row at a time so thanks!